# Assigning a const_iterator to an iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, set, const-iterator

I have the below snippet of code (which you can run here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f62134b5c125051)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::set<std::pair<const int, const int>> const mySet{{0,0}}; // value_type = std::pair<const int, const int>
    for (std::set<std::pair<const int, const int>>::iterator it  = mySet.cbegin(); it != mySet.cend(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout<<"set it = " << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
    }

    std::map<const int, const int> const myMap{{0,0}}; // value_type = std::pair<const int, const int>
    for (std::map<const int, const int>::iterator it  = myMap.cbegin(); it != myMap.cend(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout<<"map it = " << it->first << " " << it->second << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

Can someone please explain me why for *std::set* the below does not throw any error:

```
std::set<std::pair<const int, const int>>::iterator it  = mySet.cbegin();
```

while for *std::map* the below throws error (no known conversion from *_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const int, const int> >* to *_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, const int> >*) as expected:

```
std::map<const int, const int>::iterator it  = myMap.cbegin();
```

How does it work for *std::set*? Shouldn't assigning a *const_iterator* to an *iterator* always throw an error?

Comment: If you put `const` in front of `std::map` or `std::set`, I don't think you will be able to do what you're doing. You'll get a compiler error.

Comment: Also, your const doesn't apply directly to the elements of your vector or your set, it applies to the elements in your `std::pair`, so even with a non-const iterator of your vector you still won't be able to change the values of the pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify a sets elements. Keys must be `const` to ensure the invariant promised by the `set`: elements are sorted and unique. A `map`s elements are sorted too, but you can modify the mapped value of the elements (keys are `const` as well). Elements of a `std::map<A,B>` are `std::pair<const A,B>`.

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) you can read that member aliases for iterators of `std::set` are

> iterator          Constant LegacyBidirectionalIterator
>
> const_iterator     Constant LegacyBidirectionalIterator

They are both const iterators.

On the other hand for a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) they are:

> iterator  LegacyBidirectionalIterator
>
> const_iterator    Constant LegacyBidirectionalIterator

Assigning a `const_iterator` to a non-const one is wrong. Its like trying to cast `const` away by assigning a pointer to `const` to a pointer to non-const. It won't work because you cannot make something that cannot be modified modifiable. That would break const-correctness.

Comment: TIL from Vlad's answer that it is unspecified if `iterator` and `const_iterator` for `std::set` are actually the same type. So while the assignment works for OP (because they are the same type on their platform), it is incorrect in general.

Comment: thanks, fixed my last part, and I didnt notice that (even after reading said answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that explains it! As a follow-up question: is there any reason to expose both `iterator` and `const_iterator` in `std::set`? Shouldn't just one of them suffice?

Comment: @VarunHiremath containers are made to be generic (not only with regard to what elements you can store in them). You can write templates that work on containers and you know that they all have a `iterator` and `const_iterator`

Answer (score 5):

In practice `std::set<T>::iterator` is the same as `std::set<T>::const_iterator` because `std::set`'s elements are immutable. It does not have a mutable iterator type.

This is not the case for `std::map` which is why you observe different behavior.

Answer (score 3):

From the C++ 17 Standard (26.2.6 Associative containers)

> 6 iterator of an associative container is of the bidirectional
> iterator category. **For associative containers where the value type is
> the same as the key type, both iterator and const_iterator are
> constant iterators.** It is unspecified whether or not iterator and
> const_iterator are the same type.